# How to search a complex predefined regex pattern in a column using PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, dataframe1, and dataframe2, and I want to search for a complex predefined regex pattern from dataframe1 in column1 of dataframe2.

Dataframe1 with complex(here I just marked simple regex) string in regex_pattern column:

```
dataframe1 = spark.createDataFrame([
 ('rlike(test[1-9])',)
], ['regex_pattern'])

Dataframe2 with the column to search:
dataframe2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('text with test1',),
    ('text with test2',),
    ('text with test3',)
], ['column1'])

for row in dataframe1.collect():
    regex_pattern = row.regex_pattern    
    filtered_df = dataframe2.filter(col('column1').rlike(regex_pattern))    
    print(f"Results for regex pattern: {regex_pattern}")
    filtered_df.show()
    print("----------------------------------")
```

I am not getting anything as a result. Is any way to do this in both pyspark and SQL?

Comment: Avoid collect and use spark SQL functions to benefit from the executor parallelisms

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the pattern extraction. Instead of applying the regex_pattern directly, you can do `regex_pattern.split("[(|)]")[1]` and apply with `rlike`.

Means

```
pattern = regex_pattern.split("[(|)]")[1]
filtered_df = dataframe2.filter(col('column1').rlike(pattern))
```

Complete code will be like

```
dataframe1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('rlike(test[1-9])',),], ['regex_pattern'])

dataframe2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('text with test1',),
    ('text with test2',),
    ('text with test3',),
], ['column1'])

for row in dataframe1.collect():
    regex_pattern = row.regex_pattern

    pattern = regex_pattern.split("[(|)]")[1]
    filtered_df = dataframe2.filter(col('column1').rlike(pattern))

    print(f"Results for regex pattern: {regex_pattern}")
    filtered_df.show()
    print("----------------------------------")
```

Also, the same can be achieved using spark-sql

First, we need to register the dataframes as temporary views

```
dataframe1.createOrReplaceTempView("dataframe1")
dataframe2.createOrReplaceTempView("dataframe2")
```

Then execute the SQL query on them

```
query = """
    SELECT regex_pattern, column1
    FROM dataframe1, dataframe2
    WHERE column1 RLIKE SUBSTRING(regex_pattern, INSTR(regex_pattern, '(')+1, 
INSTR(regex_pattern, ')')-INSTR(regex_pattern, '(')-1)
"""

result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
```